# Use repository without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, repository

I try to figure out how to implement the repository pattern WITHOUT Entity Framework. I need to use the `ADO.NET`(disconnected) implementation,(withot `DbContext`). I know if it is possible.

I have one interface of Repository like it:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T newEntity);
    void Remove(T Entity);
    void Update(T Entity);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T Get(object key);
    void SaveChanges();                
}
```

So, I just need to know how use it with `ADO.NET` connection and Mapper or other thing.

Comment: Tip.I try this article, but it not work correct http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522226/ADO-NET-cplustheplusrightplusway

Comment: So you want to return an IQueryable for a DataTable?

Comment: I don't know. For sample. I have one entity like a Car and I need to map it with repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about the repository pattern, however your sample looks more like writing a custom linq provider.

This is actually rather complex thing, and what i think you actually need is to really use the repository pattern, where you have methods like `GetCar(int Id)` that you then implement specifically using what ever framwork you want.

The diffrence is that with a linq provider like EF, you're exposing the ability for callers to write write any query they want. However, technically this breaks the repository pattern. The idea with the Repo pattern is to contain all the queries in a single class that then expose methods for doing only what the application needs. This way you don't get queries all over your code, and you can implement only the operations your application needs.

In other words, EF is not really an example of the repository pattern, it's a way to talk to the database and create classes that represent the entities in the database. Typically you'd use EF or something similar *inside* your repository and possibly expose the actual entity types for the outside to use.

Now, writing a custom linq provider is still interesting and if you want to do it, check out this series:
http://www.jacopretorius.net/2010/01/implementing-a-custom-linq-provider.html